# Different values of "Users" metric for the same date when querying through Query Explorer and when aggregating data exported via API

Tags: google-analytics-api, talend

I'm using Talend for ETL with tGoogleAnalyticsInput component for exporting data from GA. Normally it queries for a single day (the previous), no filtering, sorting by `ga:date`

Dimensions:

- `ga:pagePath`
- `ga:date`
- `ga:country`
- `ga:hostname`
- `ga:userType`

Metrics:

- `ga:pageviews`
- `ga:sessions`
- `ga:users`
- `ga:uniquePageviews`
- `ga:bounceRate`
- `ga:pageValue`
- `ga:exitRate`

Faced with a problem: in the exported data `ga:users` is always greater than `ga:sessions`, which is almost impossible. At the same time if querying via Query Explorer this metrics seem to relate correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is query explorer? is it same observation for all dates?

Comment: The [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) uses the [Analytics Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/). If you are getting different results using a third party tool you should check with the [third party tool developer](https://help.talend.com/display/HOME/Welcome) to see if they are using the same filters and date ranges and sampling size and other parameters you are using the query explorer.

Comment: @Matt does Query Explorer set some implicit parameters when quering (i.e. some hidden from me, the user, under-the-hood actions)? Or that what I explicitly set in its interface defines the query completely?

Comment: No, and furthermore you can see the exact http request it is making at the bottom of the page.

Comment: So, I tried doing the same using GA API for java, but still facing the same anomaly. Created a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43144819/analytics-api-gives-wrong-users-count-when-fetching-paginated-result)