# Analytics API returns wrong users count when fetching paginated result

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Trying to get data using GA API for java like it's described in the [devguide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-java).

Dimensions:

- `ga:pagePath`
- `ga:date`
- `ga:country`
- `ga:hostname`
- `ga:userType`

Metrics:

- `ga:pageviews`
- `ga:sessions`
- `ga:users`
- `ga:uniquePageviews`
- `ga:bounceRate`
- `ga:pageValue`
- `ga:exitRate`

I'm querying for a single date, `max-result = 10000`. There are more than 10k rows in result, so I'm querying in a loop using `start-index`.

The problem with that query is that in the resulting data number of users is ~3 times greater than number of sessions. When I'm making a simpler query (`ga:users`, `ga:sessions` broken by `ga:date` for the same date) the ration seems valid -- `users/sessions = 0.8`

Source code is available in a [repository](https://github.com/ribitskiyb/DownloadAnalyticsReport/blob/master/src/main/java/DownloadAnalyticsReport.java)

Any ideas on how to get valid users count with that more complex query?

Comment: Check out the `Previous calculation method` section. on this link - [How users are identified for users metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2992042?hl=en). You will get some idea why the ratio is different in the mentioned scenarios.

Comment: @dikesh Read it, but it didn't give any ideas on why there are more users than sessions, keeping in mind that sessions are counted correctly in my case.

Comment: So the problem is when you take `ga:date` dimension, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sessions (an odd metric in GA) are only counted on the first hit of the sessions i.e. the landing page. When viewing page-level data, if a page is not a landing page, do not be surprised to see 0 sessions with many pageviews or users.

If you want a detailed explanation about this, read:
http://help.analyticsedge.com/googleanalytics/misunderstood-metrics-sessions-for-pages/